# Помогите разобратся с шорткодом отправки формы на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Пишу шорткод формы отправки формы трех полей в базу данных: Name, Type, Description, но что-то не пойму, как осуществляется отправка данных. Почитал, как в wordpress отправляются данные в бд, но что-то ничего не отправляется...Суть должна быть, примерно как отправка записи через админку (титулка, рубрика, текст)

car_form.php:

```
<form name="test" method="post" action="post_car.php">
<p><b>Name : </b><br>
    <input name="post_name" type="text" size="40">
</p>
<p><b>Slug : </b><br>
    <input name="slug" type="text" size="40">
</p>
<p>Description : <Br>
    <textarea name="post_content" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    <input type="reset" value="Очистить"></p>
</form>
```

functions.php:

```
add_shortcode('hsws_car_list', 'hsws_car_list_func');

function hsws_car_list_func($atts) {    
    require "car_form.php";    
}
function theme_form_init() {

    if( ! isset($_POST['submit']) ) return false;

    global $wpdb;

    $args = array(
        'post_name'     => isset($_POST['post_name']) ? esc_attr( trim($_POST['post_name']) ) : '',
        'slug'          => isset($_POST['slug']) ? esc_attr( trim($_POST['slug']) ) : '',
        'post_content'  => isset($_POST['post_content']) ? esc_attr( trim($_POST['post_content']) ) : ''
    );

}
add_action('wp', 'theme_form_init');
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно выкинуть абсолютно весь код, потому что к вопросу он имеет нулевое отношение. И показать код, которым вы пытаетесь записать что-то в базу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как обычно в php, надо читать значения массива $_POST

```
$name = $_POST['post_name'];
$slug = $_POST['slug'];
$content = $_POST['post_content'];
```

Comment: изменил код, добавил массив $_POST, но в базу всеравно не заносит...

Comment: Абалдеть! А где в вопросе слово "база"??? Вижу, что вопрос исправлен. Так тут не принято. Вам дали ответ, задайте другой вопрос

Comment: прошу прощения, не дописал...

Comment: открыл в новом вопросе, просто хочу разобраться

Comment: Новый вопрос не надо делать дубликатом. Отделите зерна от плевел: задайте вопрос только о добавлении информации в базу. Шорткод к этому не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

Comment: Вы так здорово поправили вопрос, что мой ответ стал неправильным. У вас теперь нет name="comment". Пришлось исправлять ответ, потому что такая связка вопрос-ответ только затуманивает восприятие посетителей сайта, которым может быть интересен ваш вопрос и ответ на него.

Comment: да,спасибо, не успел Вас попросить об этом, потому, что сам часто использую свои вопросы и ответы пользователей Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Делайте это через готовую функцию *Wordpress*:

```
function insertData()
{ 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $new_post = array(
            'ID' => '', 
            'post_content' => "Текст в редакторе TinyMCE" ,
            'post_title' => "Заголовок записи",
            'post_status' => "publish", //Статус записи Publish Future Draft Pending Private Trash
            'post_category' => array('23') //id нужной категории 
        );
        wp_insert_post($new_post);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
add_action( 'insert_data_hook', 'insertData' ); do_action('insert_data_hook');
```

По функции можете посмотреть вот тут: [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_insert_post)

Comment: Ваш код верен и работает, но только подскажите, пожалуйста, КАК взять данные из формы? Я своем вопросе код  написал, что там из полей  post_name, slug, post_content передается в БД

Comment: @Александр я же вам еще в прошлом вопросе ответил - используйте элементы массива $_POST

Comment: @Даниил, и еще сломалась админка по адресу my_project.com/wp-admin/edit.php (записи -> все записи) и выдает "404 — Fancy meeting you here!"

Comment: <input name="title" type="text" id="title_input">

 $new_post = array(
            'ID' => '', 
            'post_title' =>  $_POST['title']
        );

Comment: Данный метод не   вызывает конфликтов и ошибок при правильном написании. Возможно вы что то сделали не так. Нужно проанализировать ваши действия и код.

Comment: Фразы `Fancy meeting you here!` в исходном коде WordPress нет. Ищите в том, что вы там понаставили сверху.

Comment: @KAGG Design, уже разобрался, во всемирной паутине нашелся клон моего проекта и поэтому пошли неточности (просто я создал чистый проект без плагинов и без тем)